# Display Error or Information from ViewModel to View

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

How to display an Error or information (Toast,Message Box..) from view model to view.

Note: I am developing a cross platform application for Droid,Touch and Wp8.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Use a messenger or a custom object/event chain to send the error event notification to the UI. This is shown in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Sample%20-%20BestSellers/BestSellers and discussed in [Alerts or Popups in MvvmCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053535/alerts-or-popups-in-mvvmcross)
2. Provide and use a "dialog service" - like that provided by https://github.com/brianchance/MvvmCross-UserInteraction - in order to show messages
3. Use an "interaction pattern" - like that exposed by Prism - see [MvvmCross Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609018/mvvmcross-dialog/18624500#18624500)

Answer (score 1):

We've successfully tried to use the plugin 'Acr.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserDialogs' and it's working very well and has many features.

For example we have in splash screen a checking connectivity module and we used the plugin in order to display an error message:

```
public override void ReportError(string error)
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                var toast = Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogService>();
                toast.Toast("Network error, please restart the application", 5);

                });

        }
```

BTW, if you're interested in other useful plugins have a look at this page: 
https://github.com/aritchie/acrmvvmcross

Comment: IUserDialogService doesn't exist in MvvmCross. Is this the interface to your view?