# How to integrate an AlertDialog with mvvmcross

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'am trying to show notification(messages) to the user using an android alertdialog.The pattern I use for my project is MVVM(MVVMCross).

I'am passing my messages to viewmodel properties eg:

```
private string _messageHeader;

public string MessageHeader
{
    set { _messageHeader = value; }

    get { return _messageHeader = "A test messageaHeader"; }
}

private string _message;

public string Message
{
    set { _message = value; }

    get { return _message = "A test message"; }
}
```

and then I call my properties from the view and pass then pass them to the alertdialog.

```
  public StockSearchMasterViewModel StockSearchMasterViewModel
    {
        get { return (StockSearchMasterViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }



 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.Create();

 alertDialog.SetTitle(StockSearchMasterViewModel.MessageHeader);
 alertDialog.SetMessage(StockSearchMasterViewModel.Message);
 alertDialog.SetButton("OK", (s, ev) => Command.Execute(null));
 alertDialog.SetButton2("Cancel", (s, ev) => alertDialog.Hide());
 alertDialog.Show();
 .
 .
 .
```

A new message from viewmodel, a new alertdialogpopup

```
  alertDialog.SetTitle(StockSearchMasterViewModel.MessageHeader2);
 alertDialog.SetMessage(StockSearchMasterViewModel.Message2);
 alertDialog.SetButton2("OK", (s, ev) => alertDialog.Hide());
 alertDialog.Show();
```

What I'am trying to achieve here is when the user presses OK in the dialog an ICommand will execute a method in the viewmodel where there will be a second message if some condition is valid or invalid. My problem is the second message. I do not know how to pass it again to the alert dialog since the alert dialog will not stop the main thread to the .Show() (assuming that because is an asynchronous operation) and will curry on until the function has completed its cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most complete way I've found to do this is using the interaction request pattern - see: [MvvmCross Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609018/mvvmcross-dialog/18624500#18624500)

However, other ways are available - and are easier to follow - especially using the messenger or injecting a custom `IDialogService` interface. For more on these, see [Display Error or Information from ViewModel to View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448898/display-error-or-information-from-viewmodel-to-view/19449533#19449533)

Comment: Alright Stuart thanks. I will check it out and come back to you if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Don't roll your own, unless you really want to... instead, use this project by Allan Ritchie.  It has a nuget for easy integration and works great! I've used it with MvvmCross.  There used to be a MvvmCross specific one, but it's been deprecated, because this one has been generalized and works with MvvmCross, as well as without.

https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs